# use different name in area url in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3-areas, areas

I have created a area named "**User**" in my mvc project. So now i can access that area using the url **mysite.com/user**.

Now can i change the name of the area in url ? i want to access my area using the url **mysite.com/admin**

I can do this by changing the folder name of the "**user**" area. But i need to modify lot of files if i change my folder name. So is there any other way to show different name in url ? using areaRegistration.cs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your UserAreaRegistration file set up something like this:

```
public class UserAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And point to the controller/action etc that you want.

Comment: You missed the main part which is `Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}` instead of `User/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks for noticing.